# Silhouette Score with Noise (from DBSCAN)

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, noise, dbscan

I stumbled across [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html) on scikit-learn (1.2.0), where the silhouette score alongside some other metrics is computed for DBSCAN cluster assignments. These assignments include some Noise assignments.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4,
                            random_state=0)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
labels = db.labels_
print(f"Silhouette Coefficient with Noise as one cluster: {silhouette_score(X, labels):.3f}")
# 0.626
```

I find strange that there is no special treatment for Noise assigments; the cluster algorithms effectively treat them as a *one* cluster (since it's all `-1`). Is this correct?

Because if I make them individual clusters instead, I get a very different result:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(labels):
    if val == -1:
        labels[idx] = -idx

print(f"Silhouette Coefficient with Noise as individual clusters: {silhouette_score(X, labels):.3f}")
# 0.092
```

Alternatively, one could ignore the Noise assignments altogether, although this may affect comparison with other metrics:

```
mask_ok = [x >= 0 for x in labels]

print(f"Silhouette Coefficient ignoring Noise: {silhouette_score(X[mask_ok], labels[mask_ok]):.3f}")
# 0.664
```

Comment: What is the question? If the question is "*is it correct to assume that all 'noise' instances are in the same super-cluster*" the answer: It isn't a big deal. I would actual say that you are indeed right, as these data should be ignored but as you see yourself the actual difference is not huge.

Comment: The difference is substantial either way: 1) Treat each cluster individually: -85%; 2) Drop all Noise assignments: +6%.